# Send and receive ethernet data packets in CAPL

Tags: ethernet, capl

I am now approaching Ethernet. I wanted to create a CAPL able to creating a package and sending it.
I created an Ethernet network consisting of two physical ports (which I connected with an ethernet cable) and I configured the hardware (vn5640).
After building a frame ethernet in this way:

```
ethernetPacket txPacket;

txPacket.msgChannel = 1;
txPacket.Length = 100;
txPacket.word(0) = 0xc1a0;

output( txPacket );
```

how can I send this frame from port 1 and read it from port 2? i can't read what comes on Port2. My idea is to use something like that:

```
on ethernetPacket msgChannel2.*{
//read the payload 
}
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: You are missing (at least) `source` and `destination` in `txPacket`

Comment: I noticed that connecting the ports, even without set the source end destination MAC address the data travels over the LAN cable. In fact if I connect my device via ethernet to the pc, with wireshark I see the packets arrive. 
Is it possible that for the frame transfer I don't need to set the MAC address in an ethernet connection?